# Import HD Video from iPhone 4 to PC?

Tags: windows-xp, iphone

I am a Mac user and recently my friend took video with his iPhone and we can't figure out how to import the HD version of the video on his Windows XP PC. I tried emailing it and uploading to YouTube, but it always uploads the low-res version.

Comment: Updated my question with step by step instructions.

Comment: DCIM folder was empty when I clicked on it even though there are over 2000 photos on my iphone 4.

Answer (score 4):

#### Step to transfer iPhone video & pictures to PC

- Open **My Computer**

  - **If Windows Vista / 7**: Start Menu > Computer
  - **If Windows XP**: [Double-Click] *My Computer* found on desktop
- Plug iPhone via USB cable
- *Wait until the iPhone icon show up in My Computer*
- [Double-Click] the *iPhone* icon
- [Double-Click] *Internal Storage*
- [Double-Click] the *DCIM* folder
- [Double-Click] the next folder (Maybe labeled 800AAAAA)
- Search the folder for the wanted *videos* or *photo*
- [Right-Click] the *video* or *photo* you want to transfer
- Select **Copy**
- Navigate to another Windows folder to transfer it to
- [Right-Click] an open area of the destination folder
- Select **Paste**
- *Rinse and repeat for each video or photo*

*Side Note: I was surprise to find how little help there is about this topic online. Nearly every site wants to sale you its program to do this. However, this simply task is easily completed **for free** by following the steps that are provide above.*